# Unable to add styles and place holder to @Html.TextAreaFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I am using the following html tag:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(Model => Model.TaxID, 
 new {styles = "width:30%; border-color: black; maxlength: 9" @placeholder = "xxxxxxxxx"})
```

I am unable to retrieve none of the styling, max length is exceeding 9 characters and @placeholder in throwing error. Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of doing that is like this, note that it should be "style" not "styles", also you've missed one `,` between `style` and `placeholder` and the `maxlength` should be also outside of the `style`:

```
new { placeholder = "xxx", maxlength=9, style = "width:30%; border-color: black;" }
```

Comment: That was dumb of me. Thank you. Maxlength is still not working. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Harsha The maxlength is also should be outside of the style, see my updated answer.

Comment: You cleared multiple issues, in other codes too. Thank you.